# How to add filter to my table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am wondering if it's possible to add two filters (Dropdown) to my detail page. As you can see in the picture I got a detail page where it's showing information from the database. Now I wanna add two filters one which filters stad(city) and one which filters provincie(state).

[image: picture]

The dropdown menu has to add it's value by the value which is in the table row for stad(city) and provincie(state). When a stad(city) or provincie(state) is selected it will only show the person living in the selected city or state.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
           person_email, person_phonenumber,  
           address_street,address_housenumber, 
           address_city,address_state,address_zipcode, cv_path
    FROM person 
       inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address 
       inner join cv on cv.cv_id = person.person_cv";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  echo "<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <th>Voornaam</th>
  <th>Achternaam</th>
  <th>Straat</th>
  <th>Huisnummer</th>
  <th>Postcode</th>
  <th>Stad</th>
  <th>Provincie</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Mobiel</th>
  <th>cv</th>
  <th>delete</th>
  </tr>";


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<form action=delete.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_firstname"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_lastname"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_street"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_housenumber"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_zipcode"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_city"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["address_state"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_email"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["person_phonenumber"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete>" . " </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
}
else {
echo "Er is niks in het database gevonden";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The above code is the code which shows data from the database and puts it in a table. Now when I select (example) Rotterdam only Rohied should be shown in the table. Same for selecting provincie... In my database the stad is address_city and provincie is address_state. I could be wrong BUT is there a way for having all the cities in Holland to have in the dropdown menu... So when selecting Rotterdam it will show Rohied but when selecting an other random city it will say there is no one in the database living in the selected city ( or state).

Comment: *"I am wondering if it's possible..."* Anything is possible. Did you have a specific question?

Comment: Well I tried lots of codes on the internet but non of them were working. And I really have no idea where to start. I am new to PHP so I hope I can get help from here to help me add two dropdown menu's which can/will do the above

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: I see wait ill upload my code for using the dropdown menu.

Comment: You have to put the information from what you want filter into "Where" statement on your query like "WHERE address_city LIKE '%{$filter_city}%'